# Configure vmware-tools without an initrd image?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware, initrd

Is it possible to run `vmware-tools` without an initrd? I don't know why I should use an initrd and it makes my kernel compilation more complicated. I can boot into my kernel without initrd but when I want to install `vmware-tools` it gives me an error message:

```
There was an error generating the initrd (1). Error /sbin/mkinitd -k vmlinuz...
```

Can I reboot?

Edit: It doesn't work without initrd. I've temporarily enabled it and it adds Kernel Modules: vmxnet3 vmxnet to the initrd?